# Java: Inheritance and declarations

Tags: java, inheritance, declaration

What is the difference between the following declarations? And when are they used?

```
ParentClass child = new ChildClass();
ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
```

...if I already have this:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {}
```

Comment: First instance will have access to child *and* parent methods, variables etc. Second instance will be a standalone instance and will only have access to its own methods, variables etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that you have a method `foo()` declared in `ParentClass` and a method `bar()` in `ChildClass`. Since `ChildClass` extends `ParentClass` - it also inherits the `foo()` method.

In the first case you wouldn't be able to call `child.bar();` because `ParentClass` doesn't have a method called `bar()`.

Same thing applies to variables, inner classes, etc. For further information, consult the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).